# Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error

Tags: flask

Hi good day I have a small project in flask the projects is csv tools Merge, Compare, and Update CSV Files here the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoTwS.png)

the problem is I dont get any error problem but I got this error when i try to use the

Merge, Compare and Update CSV Files error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jAyz.png)

heres the error from terminal:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDUA5.png)

here my code from app.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file1 = request.files["file1"]
        file2 = request.files["file2"]
        compare_file = request.files.get("comparison_file") 

        # ... (Error handling for CSV files)

        # Load DataFrames
        df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
        df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)

        # Merge and remove duplicates (initial result)
        merged_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()

        if compare_file:
            compare_df = pd.read_csv(compare_file)

            # Find new entries (not present in the initial merged data)
            new_entries_df = compare_df[~compare_df.isin(merged_df).all(axis=1)]

            # Merge new entries only with the initial merged data
            merged_df = pd.concat([merged_df, new_entries_df]).drop_duplicates()

        # Save and send the final result
        merged_df.to_csv("updated_result.csv")
        return send_file("updated_result.csv", as_attachment=True)

    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSV Tools by Wu Dev Team</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CSV Tools</h1>

    <h2>Merge CSV Files and Remove Duplicates</h2>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file1" required><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="file2" required><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="merge_only">Merge Only</button>
    </form>

    <h2>Merge, Compare and Update CSV Files</h2>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file1" required><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="file2" required><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="comparison_file"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="merge_compare">Merge and Update</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

hope Guys can help me I am just a biginner in python:(

the goal is when I click the submit button of merge and update, the result must collect all new data row that non-existing in the merged csv file and automatically download it.